# How to convert datetime.time to datetime.datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to subtract 2 times and they both are in datetime.time format. How to convert them to datetime.datetime in python.

> Error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

I have a question to which I need a workaround to write my code.

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html? Logically it doesn't make sense to subtract times unless you also know what day they are, there are various options depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

time1 = datetime.time(1, 0, 0)
time2 = datetime.time(1, 30, 0)

today = datetime.date.today()

datetime1 = datetime.datetime.combine(today, time1)
datetime2 = datetime.datetime.combine(today, time2)

time_diff = datetime2 - datetime1

# The result is a timedelta object
print(time_diff)
```

You may use a common datetime, here today, and then subtract them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime.combine()` function **BUT!!** be aware that there are potential pitfalls to this approach.

```py
import datetime
t1 = datetime.time(8)  # 8:00 AM
t2 = datetime.time(17) # 5:00 PM
d = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1) # Arbitrary date
delta = datetime.datetime.combine(d, t2) - datetime.datetime.combine(d, t1)
print(delta)
```

Prints:

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=32400)
```

Potential pitfalls:

- Does not account for daylight savings
- 1AM minus 11PM is *negative* 22 hours, that may not be what you want
- Note that if the `tzinfo` is present in the `time` object, it will be inherited by the `datetime` object—this may or may not be what you want